# Using phoenix-spark plugin to insert an ARRAY Type

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, hbase, apache-phoenix

I have a problem. I have a Spark `RDD` that I have to store inside an HBase table. We use the Apache-phoenix layer to dialog with the database. There a column of the table that is defined as an `UNSIGNED_SMALLINT ARRAY`:

```
CREATE TABLE EXAMPLE (..., Col10 UNSIGNED_SMALLINT ARRAY, ...);
```

As stated in the Phoenix documentation, that you can fine [here](https://phoenix.apache.org/language/datatypes.html#array), `ARRAY` data type is backend up by the `java.sql.Array`.

I'm using the *phoenix-spark* plugin to save data of the `RDD` inside the table. The problem is that I don't know how to create an instance of `java.sql.Array`, not having any kind of `Connection` object. An extract of the code follows (code is in Scala language):

```
// Map RDD into an RDD of sequences or tuples
rdd.map {
  value =>
    (/* ... */
     value.getArray(),   // Array of Int to convert into an java.sql.Array
     /* ... */
    )
}.saveToPhoenix("EXAMPLE", Seq(/* ... */, "Col10", /* ... */), conf, zkUrl)
```

Which is the correct way of go on? Is there a way to do want I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The guys at Phoenix have answered via email to the above question. I report the answer to leave the wisdom for the people who will come.

> For saving arrays, you can use the plain old scala Array type. You can see the tests for an example:
>   https://github.com/apache/phoenix/blob/master/phoenix-spark/src/it/scala/org/apache/phoenix/spark/PhoenixSparkIT.scala#L408-L427
>
> Note that saving arrays is only supported in Phoenix **4.5.0**, although the patch is quite small if you need to apply it yourself:
>   https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PHOENIX-1968

Nice answer. Thanks to guys at Phoenix.